# How do I write a command block to detect if no online player has a specific score and execute a command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
execute unless score @p playerid = step10 time run say no players
```

As the `@p` finds the nearest person, it doesn't check all players at once and therefore fails to not run when someone online has the score.

How do I get it to run only when nobody online has the score?

In this case, a `playerid` value of 10.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something, what is `step10`?

Comment: fake player i use for stand in on fixed numbers usefull for alot of things @kusobito

Comment: Ah ok. I am not sure if this is the correct syntax, but the command would be similar to this: `/execute unless entity @a[scores={playerid=10}] run say no players`

Answer (score 1):

So if you'd like to use your current setup you could use this command:

```
/execute as @a unless score @s playerid = step10 time run say no players
```

This will execute as all players, using the `@s` selector after `score`, because it only allows 1 entity. So you can get around that with adding `as @a` in front.

You could also use this command wich does the same thing but now you can compare to a fixed amount:

```
/execute unless entity @a[scores={playerid=10..10}] run say no players
```

The `scores={playerid=10..10}` affects any player with the score "playerid" from 10 to 10, so if you want to test from 1 to 10 you would put `1..10` instead.